# Nested backticks in bash script not working

Tags: bash, backticks, word-count

I'm trying the following in a bash script:

```
COUNT=`cat "$NEWLIST" | wc -l | awk \' { print $1 } \` `
```

where NEWLIST is a string containing a list of files, one per line. But I get this error:

```
command substitution: line 74: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
```

Why is that failing? How do I use nested backticks?

(basically I'm trying to strip whitespace from the result of wc, but I'd also like to know how to use nested backticks anyways)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing ' and `

```
COUNT=`cat "$NEWLIST" | wc -l | awk ' { print $1 } ' `
```

Answer (score 8):

That's one reason you should use `$()` instead of backticks.

Also, there's no need for `cat` or AWK:

```
COUNT=$(wc -l < "$NEWLIST")
```

Comment: Thanks. I was originally using awk because in my Mac OSX terminal, wc was producing leading whitespace. But it seems to be gone with the above expression.

Answer (score 2):

That second "escaped backtick" should actually be a single quote, just like the first one. Also, be careful with the `$1` there.

Comment: why do I need to be careful with the $1?